What does "She was already suited" mean?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

To ring her? To throw on his clothes and hurry round there, to be received as her secret lover, creeping away with the dawn?
Too late. She was already suited.
Suddenly, he wanted her dreadfully. He could not bear the spaces round him that did not contain her, he longed for her laughing trembling body as she cried to him, calling him her only true, her best lover, she wanted none other, ever. “Women are lawless, George,” she had told him once, when they lay in rare peace.

Does that suggest that Ann already had a partner? If yes, then what does "was already suited" mean literally?

There is an old word to "pay suit" which means among other things to "court" or try to persuade someone into marriage or a romantic relationship. The word "suitor" - one who pays suit - is better known, at least to readers of period romantic novels.
I think "suited" here is a play on words based on "suitor" - jokingly if the "suitor" is successful then the object of their "suiting" has been "suited". Smiley is too late to pay suit to her himself, as she is already in a relationship.  These are not standard uses of the words, but fairly deducable in a playful way.
And yes, it means Ann already has a partner, a suitor who has successfully "suited" her.

Ann is of course Smiley's estranged wife; he can't go to her home as though he were her secret lover because she already has another lover.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Smiley is too late to pay suit to her himself" - he and Ann are already married.

Married but estranged. If you like, married to Smiley but in a real relationship with someone else and not him. He can't go and persuade her to actually love him or sleep with him because she has someone else despite thei marriage.  It's one of the ongoing themes of the Smiley books, Smiley's inability to have a real loving relationship with his wife.

There is also the expression: Suit yourself. So, if she was suited, she has found someone who suited her. As in matched. I don't think the pay suit works here.

There's a definition in Webster New World Dictionary that says "to please; satisfy [anything that suits your fancy]", which may fit this case. That's similar to the meaning in "suit yourself", as @Lambie mentioned, which means "to do as one pleases".

@SilentSojourner Yes, though the passive is what makes it amusing.
